# Angular loading values in component from constructor

Tags: angular, constructor, routes, initialization

I am facing a problem to get initialized values for a component.
I have a page I set a route to. When loading the route (angular routing), the values in the constructor of the component are set but it seems to skip a part of the constructor so the values are not as wished.

Here is my constructor:

```
public userQMail: QMails[] = [];
public low: string;
public med: string;
public all: string;

constructor(private qms: QMailsService) {
this.userQMail = this.qms.userQMails;
let x: number = 0;
let y: number = 0;
this.userQMail.forEach((e) => {
  if (parseInt(e.label) <= 30) {
    x++;
  } else {
    y++;
  }
});
this.low = x.toString();
this.med = y.toString();
this.all = (x + y).toString();
}
```

Values I get in view are 0, 0, 0 (for low, med, all) so it skips the forEach... And I don't know why.
When i change page and go back the values are right. So I guess this is some kind of Initialization Priority Issue? Or does it have to do sth. with the routing?

On first load of the component, everything inside the forEach is skipped...

I am pretty new to Angular, so I may not understand a concept here.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the `userQEmails` in the `QMailsService` are loaded asynchronously or atleast initialized after the constructor in this component is called. If this is the case, this explains why the values are all zero.

You can solve this by accessing the value in the service directly with a getter, e.g.

```
get low(): string {
    return this.qms.userQMails?.filter(x => parseInt(e.label) <= 30)?.length?.toString();
}

get mid(): string {
    return this.qms.userQMails?.filter(x => parseInt(e.label) > 30)?.length?.toString();
}

get all(): string {
    return this.qms.userQMails?.length?.toString();
}
```

You should also look into / learn more about rxjs [observables](https://rxjs.dev/guide/observable) and data streams to make fix this in a cleaner and more maintainable way.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Can't get it working atm, but will have a further look on the topics you stated.